# How to Declare global Variable Using Session or Application in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Please am in need of some help on how i can declare a global variable with a value that comes from database...

I have two branches in the application with different _Layout and i render the view with layout base on the category id that comes from the database, now i want a situation were by, when a user login to the app the main layout display two branches and when the user choose a branch, i want to get the category id of that branch from the database and store it in a HttpContext.Session["CategoryID"] OR HttpContext.Application["CategoryID"] so that i can use this variable and render the appropriate layout through out the application not UNLESS the user go back to the main menu and choose another branch before the value can change and render a different layout with all the views.

this is what i tried but it isn't working

```
//GET: /Branch/
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var BranchId = _schoolService.getBranchById(id).SchoolCategoryId;

        HttpContext.Session["BranchId"] = BranchId;
        HttpContext.Application["BranchId"] = BranchId;

        int branch = (int)HttpContext.Session["BranchId"];

        if (branch == 1)
        {
            return View("Index", "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBranch.cshtml");
        }
        else if (branch == 2)
        {
            return View("Index", "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSecodary.cshtml");
        }
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Error");

    }
```

tried to store the variable from the entry of the of branch controller so that i can call it in any view and controller.

even tried using a BaseController and inherit it in other controllers but it isn't working still.

So please am i missing something here or is there any other way i can make it work the way i want please help and thank you for your time...

Comment: I hardcoded the line 
    `var BranchId = _schoolService.getBranchById(id).SchoolCategoryId;`


to `var BranchId=1;`

it works for me. 

Are you sure that branchId variable is assigned a value ??

Comment: yes when I did it @ first it worked very well for the first but after then it didnt work for other views and even tried the index page again and am having Null Exception

Comment: Please put your application on debug and break on the line 
`var BranchId = _schoolService.getBranchById(id).SchoolCategoryId;`

and press F10. Hover on BranchId and see if it is assigned a value.

Comment: okay will do that now and get back to you

Comment: just tried that and it working quite well and the BranchId has a value.

Comment: let me try the variable in another view and check if still remains.

Comment: is it being retrieved in 
       `int branch = (int)HttpContext.Session["BranchId"];` ?

Comment: Yes and i think it is working now because i just tried reloading the page and it didn't hit my first brake point which is @ the opening brace `{`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your code with hardcoded BranchId=1, and it works. At least for the Index() action, but I guess you want it to work for all actions in every controller.

Try something like this:

Search for ~/_ViewStart.cshtml 
and replace the content with this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    string layoutId = HelperMethods.GetLayoutId();

    if(layoutId != null) {
        switch(HelperMethods.GetLayoutId())
        {
            case "1":
                Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout1.cshtml";
                break;
            case "2":
                Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

_ViewStart.cshtml specifies the layout file for every view, that does not specifiy it itself. Therefore writing your code into this file results in one layout for the whole application, depending on your branch thing. Note: In order for this to work, there must not be any Layout classification in the view files under ~/Views/*folder*/*file*.cshtml .

**Edit:**
You could use some static methods to set or get the layout ids. For example clicking a button calls SetLayoutId(1) and in the _ViewStart.cshtml you receive that from the session.

```
using System.Web;

namespace SomeMVC
{
    public static class HelperMethods
    {
        public static string GetLayoutId()
        {
            return (string) HttpContext.Current.Session["LayoutId"];
        }

        public static void SetLayoutId(string id)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["LayoutId"] = id;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay i like this but where is the `getBranch()` method coming from please. please write the answer in full so that i can understand you please thank you

Comment: Okay let me try this.

Comment: I added the code a bit so it doesn't throw exceptions and also tested it :)

Comment: it working fine thanks.. so please how do i set default case for the first start to use `_Layout.cshtml` if i should use this `case 0` am I correct?

Comment: It working fine now thank you for you time i added `default: _Layout.cshtml break;` Thanx again for your time

Comment: why `string` instead of int?

Comment: Had to be an object-type on my setup, because the getter of the session states can return null